# Passing an array of data between sibling components in Angular 2

Tags: angular

**Is there a way to pass data between two sibling components in angular 2?**

School application:

The user of the app will pick one or more schools from a list(schoolData.component.ts). These picks are used to filter an array of school data. The data will be presented in a calendar(calendar.component.ts).

Structure of the application:

├── app/

├── ├── app.component.ts

├── ├── app.module.ts

├── ├── main.ts

├── ├── schoolData/

├── ├── ├── schoolData.component.ts

├── ├── ├── schoolData.service.ts

├── ├── ├── html/

├── ├── ├── ├── schoolData.component.html

├── ├── ├── css/

├── ├── ├── ├── SchoolData.component.css

├── ├── calendar/

├── ├── ├── calendar.component.ts

├── ├── ├── html/

├── ├── ├── calendar.component.html

├── ├── ├── css/

├── ├── ├── calendar.component.css

**How do I pass data from the schoolData.component to the calendar.component?**

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: I ended up using the html5 local storage API to store variables locally on the browser so that other components could get the data from stored variables. I understand that this solution is a hack, but it worked well since I wanted to store the user data anyways.

Comment: This can be done with a service that stores the data and on each component a get or set accordingly to your needs

Comment: See this approach https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/